# pls help me with the #na error and #value error available in pic

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, sumifs

pls help me with the #na error and #value error in the picenter image description here

[image]

Comment: Your ranges aren't the same size... differing number of columns.

Comment: You will want to do two SUMIFS, one for each column and add the results together.

Answer (score 0):

What is it you are trying to do?

The #Value error comes from trying to sum two columns together with the sumifs function. The NA error is from the J1 cell reference needing to be absolute. Other wise you are checking to see if any cell in D or E column have your formula in it.

Try;

```
=((Sumifs(D2:D20057,C2,I2,D2,$J$1)+(Sumifs(E2:E20057,C2,I2,D2,$J$1))
```

Assuming that you want all of the D and E cells to just check against the -16 in J1.